# how to connect to ethernet printer throught python?

Tags: python, printing, python-2.7, receipt

How can i connect and send data to a Ethernet receipt printer Epson-T88V through python2.7, i have set the ipaddress of the Ethernet printer manually and the utility software communication is also successful. 
How do i detect and connect to these printers and send data to print. Is there and module for Ethernet connection in python. 
Using more than one Ethernet printer and separate data to be printed simultaneously from a single system, i am using windows xp and python 2.7
I have added the printer as my default printer, how can i access this TCP/IP printer
hope i am clear
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import usb
from PIL import Image
import time
import os, sys
import win32print
from constants import *
from exceptions import *
class Escpos:
    """ ESC/POS Printer object """
    handle    = None
    device    = None

    def __init__(self,interface=0, in_ep=0x100, out_ep=0x01) :
        self.interface = interface
        self.in_ep     = in_ep
        self.out_ep    = out_ep
        if sys.version_info >= (3,):
            raw_data = bytes ("This is a test\n", "utf-8")
        else:
            raw_data = "This is Shiva's test\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"

        self.hPrinter = win32print.OpenPrinter ("Auto EPSON TM-T88V ReceiptE4 on SYSTEM")
        self.handle = win32print.OpenPrinter ("EPSON TM-T88V")
    def _raw(self, msg):
        try:
            self.hJob = win32print.StartDocPrinter (self.hPrinter, 1, ("test of raw data", None, "RAW"))
            self.hJob = win32print.StartDocPrinter (self.handle, 1, ("test of raw data", None, "RAW"))
            try:
                win32print.WritePrinter(self.handle, msg)
                win32print.WritePrinter(self.hPrinter, msg)
                win32print.EndDocPrinter (self.handle)
                win32print.EndDocPrinter (self.hPrinter)
            finally:
                print self.hJob
        finally:
            print self.hJob

    def _check_image_size(self, size):
        """Check and fix the size of the image to 32 bits"""
        if size % 32 == 0:
            return (0, 0)
        else:
            image_border = 32 - (size % 32)
            if (image_border % 2) == 0:
                return (image_border / 2, image_border / 2)
            else:
                return (image_border / 2, (image_border / 2) + 1)


    def _print_image(self, line, size):
        i = 0
        cont = 0
        buffer = ""

        self._raw(S_RASTER_N)
        buffer = "%02X%02X%02X%02X" % (((size[0]/size[1])/8), 0, size[1], 0)
        self._raw(buffer.decode('hex'))
        buffer = ""

        while i < len(line):
            hex_string = int(line[i:i+8],2)
            buffer += "%02X" % hex_string
            i += 8
            cont += 1
            if cont % 4 == 0:
                self._raw(buffer.decode("hex"))
                buffer = ""
                cont = 0


    def image(self, img):
        """Parse image and then print it"""
        pixels   = []
        pix_line = ""
        im_left  = ""
        im_right = ""
        switch   = 0
        img_size = [ 0, 0 ]

        im_open = Image.open(img)
        im = im_open.convert("RGB")

        if im.size[0] > 512:
            print  "WARNING: Image is wider than 512 and could be truncated at print time "
        if im.size[1] > 255:
            raise ImageSizeError()

        im_border = self._check_image_size(im.size[0])
        for i in range(im_border[0]):
            im_left += "0"
        for i in range(im_border[1]):
            im_right += "0"

        for y in range(im.size[1]):
            img_size[1] += 1
            pix_line += im_left
            img_size[0] += im_border[0]
            for x in range(im.size[0]):
                img_size[0] += 1
                RGB = im.getpixel((x, y))
                im_color = (RGB[0] + RGB[1] + RGB[2])
                im_pattern = "1X0"
                pattern_len = len(im_pattern)
                switch = (switch - 1 ) * (-1)
                for x in range(pattern_len):
                    if im_color <= (255 * 3 / pattern_len * (x+1)):
                        if im_pattern[x] == "X":
                            pix_line += "%d" % switch
                        else:
                            pix_line += im_pattern[x]
                        break
                    elif im_color > (255 * 3 / pattern_len * pattern_len) and im_color <= (255 * 3):
                        pix_line += im_pattern[-1]
                        break 
            pix_line += im_right
            img_size[0] += im_border[1]

        self._print_image(pix_line, img_size)


    def barcode(self, code, bc, width, height, pos, font):
        """ Print Barcode """
        # Align Bar Code()
        self._raw(TXT_ALIGN_CT)
        # Height
        if height >=2 or height <=6:
            self._raw(BARCODE_HEIGHT)
        else:
            raise BarcodeSizeError()
        # Width
        if width >= 1 or width <=255:
            self._raw(BARCODE_WIDTH)
        else:
            raise BarcodeSizeError()
        # Font
        if font.upper() == "B":
            self._raw(BARCODE_FONT_B)
        else: # DEFAULT FONT: A
            self._raw(BARCODE_FONT_A)
        # Position
        if pos.upper() == "OFF":
            self._raw(BARCODE_TXT_OFF)
        elif pos.upper() == "BOTH":
            self._raw(BARCODE_TXT_BTH)
        elif pos.upper() == "ABOVE":
            self._raw(BARCODE_TXT_ABV)
        else:  # DEFAULT POSITION: BELOW 
            self._raw(BARCODE_TXT_BLW)
        # Type 
        if bc.upper() == "UPC-A":
            self._raw(BARCODE_UPC_A)
        elif bc.upper() == "UPC-E":
            self._raw(BARCODE_UPC_E)
        elif bc.upper() == "EAN13":
            self._raw(BARCODE_EAN13)
        elif bc.upper() == "EAN8":
            self._raw(BARCODE_EAN8)
        elif bc.upper() == "CODE39":
            self._raw(BARCODE_CODE39)
        elif bc.upper() == "ITF":
            self._raw(BARCODE_ITF)
        elif bc.upper() == "NW7":
            self._raw(BARCODE_NW7)
        else:
            raise BarcodeTypeError()
        # Print Code
        if code:
            self._raw(code)
        else:
            raise exception.BarcodeCodeError()


    def text(self, txt):
        """ Print alpha-numeric text """
        if txt:
            self._raw(txt)
        else:
            raise TextError()


    def set(self, align='left', font='a', type='normal', width=1, height=1):
        """ Set text properties """
        # Align
        if align.upper() == "CENTER":
            self._raw(TXT_ALIGN_CT)
        elif align.upper() == "RIGHT":
            self._raw(TXT_ALIGN_RT)
        elif align.upper() == "LEFT":
            self._raw(TXT_ALIGN_LT)
        # Font
        if font.upper() == "B":
            self._raw(TXT_FONT_B)
        else:  # DEFAULT FONT: A
            self._raw(TXT_FONT_A)
        # Type
        if type.upper() == "B":
            self._raw(TXT_BOLD_ON)
            self._raw(TXT_UNDERL_OFF)
        elif type.upper() == "U":
            self._raw(TXT_BOLD_OFF)
            self._raw(TXT_UNDERL_ON)
        elif type.upper() == "U2":
            self._raw(TXT_BOLD_OFF)
            self._raw(TXT_UNDERL2_ON)
        elif type.upper() == "BU":
            self._raw(TXT_BOLD_ON)
            self._raw(TXT_UNDERL_ON)
        elif type.upper() == "BU2":
            self._raw(TXT_BOLD_ON)
            self._raw(TXT_UNDERL2_ON)
        elif type.upper == "NORMAL":
            self._raw(TXT_BOLD_OFF)
            self._raw(TXT_UNDERL_OFF)
        # Width
        if width == 2 and height != 2:
            self._raw(TXT_NORMAL)
            self._raw(TXT_2WIDTH)
        elif height == 2 and width != 2:
            self._raw(TXT_NORMAL)
            self._raw(TXT_2HEIGHT)
        elif height == 2 and width == 2:
            self._raw(TXT_2WIDTH)
            self._raw(TXT_2HEIGHT)
        else: # DEFAULT SIZE: NORMAL
            self._raw(TXT_NORMAL)


    def cut(self, mode=''):
        """ Cut paper """
        # Fix the size between last line and cut
        # TODO: handle this with a line feed
        print "The Cut mode is",mode
        self._raw("\n\n\n\n\n\n")
        if mode.upper() == "PART":
            print "The Cut mode PartCut is true"
            self._raw(PAPER_PART_CUT)
        else: # DEFAULT MODE: FULL CUT
            self._raw(PAPER_FULL_CUT)


    def cashdraw(self, pin):
        """ Send pulse to kick the cash drawer """
        if pin == 2:
            self._raw(CD_KICK_2)
        elif pin == 5:
            self._raw(CD_KICK_5)
        else:
            raise CashDrawerError()


    def hw(self, hw):
        """ Hardware operations """
        if hw.upper() == "INIT":
            self._raw(HW_INIT)
        elif hw.upper() == "SELECT":
            self._raw(HW_SELECT)
        elif hw.upper() == "RESET":
            self._raw(HW_RESET)
        else: # DEFAULT: DOES NOTHING
            pass


    def control(self, ctl):
        """ Feed control sequences """
        if ctl.upper() == "LF":
            self._raw(CTL_LF)
        elif ctl.upper() == "FF":
            self._raw(CTL_FF)
        elif ctl.upper() == "CR":
            self._raw(CTL_CR)
        elif ctl.upper() == "HT":
            self._raw(CTL_HT)
        elif ctl.upper() == "VT":
            self._raw(CTL_VT)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should look at using [pkipplib](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pkipplib/0.07) or [wxpython](http://wiki.wxpython.org/index.cgi/Printing) libraries.

Comment: thanks for ur reply i am trying with pkipplib, but it need pycups which on installation is raising "error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat"

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used pycups myself so can't answer this.

Comment: @alexmartelli: - do u have any idea or links to help me in this